# Question about how to use NestWhileList

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I start with:

```
n = 2228;
m = n/2;
PreviousPrime[n_] := NextPrime[n, -1]
```

I use `NestList` to build the following list:

```
primedesert = Drop[NestList[PreviousPrime, m, 18], 1]
```

which gives:

> ```
> {1109, 1103, 1097, 1093, 1091, 1087, 1069, 1063, 1061, 1051, 1049, 
>  1039, 1033, 1031, 1021, 1019, 1013, 1009}
> ```

Next, I build the list:

```
mirage = n - primedesert
```

> ```
> {1119, 1125, 1131, 1135, 1137, 1141, 1159, 1165, 1167, 1177, 1179,
>  1189, 1195, 1197, 1207, 1209, 1215, 1219}
> ```

Notice that:

```
PrimeQ[mirage]
```

gives

> ```
> {False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 
>  False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False}
> ```

```
p = PreviousPrime[Last[primedesert]]
```

gives

> `997`

```
q = (n - p)
```

gives

> `1231`

```
PrimeQ[q]
```

gives

> `True`

```
 p + q == n
```

gives:

> `True`

If you look at the definition of `primedesert` above you will see that I'm using the number 18 because I know the number of iterations to reach the point {p, q} beforehand.

What I want instead is to build the list like `primedesert` using `NestWhileList` so that I don't have to worry about computing the number of iterations beforehand.  So I tried

```
NestWhileList[PreviousPrime, m, ! PrimeQ[n - PreviousPrime]]
```

but, I get

> `{1114}`

My question is: how can I use `NestWhileList` to build the list like `primedesert`?

Comment: `NestWhileList` is expecting the test to be a function.  Perhaps `(!PrimeQ[ n-PreviousPrime[#] ])&`?

Comment: @jjc385 I tried:                                                                                   NestWhileList[PreviousPrime[#] &, m, ! PrimeQ[n - PreviousPrime[#]]] and I unfortunately get the same wrong result {1114}.

Comment: I think you're missing an `&` at the end of the last argument -- `NestWhileList[PreviousPrime, m, ! PrimeQ[n - PreviousPrime[#]] &]` seems to work.  Note also that you might find `Most@NestWhileList[PreviousPrime, m, ! PrimeQ[n - #] &]` to be cleaner.

Comment: @jjc385 Both answers work! Thank you for your help! :-)

Comment: LengthOfPrimeDesert = 
 Length[Drop[Most@NestWhileList[PreviousPrime, m, ! PrimeQ[n - #] &], 
   1]]        gives 18.

Comment: I was using [`Most`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Most.html) as an equivalent alternative to  `Drop[ list, 1 ]`  -- does using only one of them give you what you desire?

Comment: @jjc385 I apologize for not reading your text message until now.  Yes; both Drop and Most are necessary; if you use only Drop you might missed the Goldbach partition point.  Example: n=16; goldbachpair[n_?EvenQ] /; n > 3 := 
 Block[{m = PrimePi[n/2], p}, 
  While[! PrimeQ[n - (p = Prime[m])], m--]; {p, n - p}]

Comment: goldbachpair[n] gives {5,11}.  m=n/2 gives 8. PrimeQ[m] gives False.  PreviousPrime[n_] := NextPrime[n, -1]  , LPD[n_?EvenQ] := 
 Quiet[Module[{m = n/2}, 
   If[PrimeQ[m], lpd = 0, 
    lpd = Length[
      Drop[Most@NestWhileList[PreviousPrime, m, ! PrimeQ[n - #] &], 
       1]]]; lpd]],    L=LPD[n] gives 1. primedesert = Drop[NestList[PreviousPrime, m, L], 1] gives {7}; mirage = n - primedesert gives {9}; PrimeQ[mirage] gives {False}. p = PreviousPrime[Last[primedesert]] gives 5. q = (n - p) gives 11.  PrimeQ[q] gives True. p + q == n gives True.  {5, 11} is the  "Golbach point".